# Unable to read value from properties file in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, selenium, automation, properties-file

Actually i'm trying to get the values from JSP page and writing those data to config.properties file.
I'm able to write the data in it.
But i can't able to read the property values from that config.properties file.

```
public static void startup() throws ReflectiveOperationException, Exception {
        String configPath ="C:/Selenium_Automation_JSP/automation/src/com/selenium/config/config.properties";
        DriverScript Test = new DriverScript(configPath);
        System.out.println("Config path loaded");
        Test.start(configPath);
    }

        public void start(String configPath) throws ReflectiveOperationException, IllegalArgumentException, Exception{



            System.out.println(configPath);

            CONFIG=new Properties();
            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(configPath);
            CONFIG.load(fs);

            String mapFile=CONFIG.getProperty("Suite");

            System.out.println(mapFile);
            SuiteXLS  = new Xls_Reader(mapFile);
```

In console, i can see the path of config.properties. But while reading the file, it shows the following error,

```
Config path loaded
C:/Selenium_Automation_JSP/automation/src/com/selenium/config/config.properties
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:124)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:87)
    at com.selenium8x8.xlsoperations.Xls_Reader.<init>(Xls_Reader.java:43)
    at com.selenium8x8.driver.DriverScript.start(DriverScript.java:106)
    at com.selenium8x8.driver.DriverScript.startup(DriverScript.java:85)
    at com.selenium8x8.servlet.ControlServlet.doPost(ControlServlet.java:120)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

This is my **config.properties** file

```
TestURL=http://agents.8x8pilot.com/
Suite=C:/Selenium_Automation_JSP/automation/src/com/selenium/xls/Suite.xlsx
ObjectRepository=C:/Selenium_Automation_JSP/automation/src/com/selenium/xls/ObjectRepository.xls
DataManagement=C:Selenium_Automation_JSP/automation/src/com/selenium/xls/StoredData.xls
```

But i can't able to read the "Suite" property value..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to **change your configPath** to :

```
String configPath ="C:\\Selenium_Automation_JSP\\automation\\src\\com\\selenium\\config\\config.properties";
```

and then load it like:

```
CONFIG.load(new FileInputStream(configPath));
```

**EDIT :** As per @sircapsalot , absolute paths is a bad idea. If you think your configPath will change, you can use it to change it to an absolute path using regex or something like that and then pass it to the `FileInputStream`. I should make it clear that  FileInputStream does need absolute paths for working.

Comment: this is bad.. don't recommend absolute paths like this! Use `ClassLoader`s

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CONFIG=new Properties();
CONFIG.store(new FileOutputStream(configPath), null);
CONFIG.getProperty("Suite");
```